# Allow null in model when using Code first

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have an model like this:

```
 public class EquipmentEmployee
{
    public int EquipmentEmployeeID { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

    public int RequisitionID { get; set; }
    public Requisition Requisition { get; set; }

    public DateTime From { get; set; }

    public DateTime To { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

}
```

I use Mvc scaffolding for creating my controllers, repositories and views. Int the create View I'm not able to POST since I dont have values for "to" and "RequisitionID". I have not added [Required] to them. Is this possible? To POST and have those two null?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should declare optional fields using a nullable type

```
public int? RequisitionID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Dammit, DateTime was a struct. I was going crazy wondering why the hell was it making it NOT NULL, thinking it was reference type.

Comment: You might have to use Nullable<int> instead - new MVC 5 does not allow the ? for FKs

Answer (score 3):

To accept the null values you can use the following solution.

```
public int? RequisitionID { get; set; }
```